# how to insert all values in dropdown list to mysql table using jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have 1 applications in my project called select.jsp  ,in select.jsp i have one dropdown box, if i don't select anything in dropdown box ,all the values in that box should insert in mysql table using jsp,please help me to solve this.

i tried the following code:

select.jsp contains the following code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="frm1" name="frm_addUser" method="post" action="./index.jsp">
    Select Programming Language:
    <select name="lang" id="t">
    <option value="select">select language</option>
    <option value="C/C++">C/C++</option>
    <option value="C#">C#</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="text" id="cmblen" name="cmbna">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ><br>
    </form>

    <%!
    String tlen="";
    String languages="";%>
    <%
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","sumith");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int j=0;
        String lang[]=request.getParameterValues("lang");



        for(int i=0; i<lang.length; i++)
        {
            //languages+=lang[i]+", ";
            j=st.executeUpdate("insert into combo(language) values('"+lang[i]+"')");
        }



            out.println("Data is successfully inserted into database.");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //out.println(e);
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

            %>


    </body>
    </html>
```

but myproblem is in mysql table i am able to insert only firstvalue of combobox,but the remaining values are not inserting in to the mysql table,can you please help me to solve this.

Comment: first validate the input field whether value is selected or not, if not selected then write a loop based on count of dropdown options then store the each and every value in DB until loop ends.

Comment: @mahesh thanks for reply,can you please give me some code.

Comment: try yourself it will improve your skills,depending on others is not recommended and SE is not meant for this type of questions.

Comment: @mahesh thanks again ,i tried what you said and i have updated my post also can you please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!selectedValue.equals("select")) {
    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into combo (combocol) values ('" + selectedValue + "')");
  } else {
    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into combo (combocol) values ('C/C++'),('C#'),('java'),('perl'),('python')");
  }
```